# Switching between two subapps

Tags: iphone, uiapplicationdelegate, uiwindow

Hei there,

right now I'm trying to connect two "seperate" Subapps with one view. On this view, which will be launched on app start, I have two buttons one to start Subapp A and another one to start Subapp B. Subapp A & B both have their own UINavigationController and the only way to switch from one Subapp to another is the start view and a button somewhere on a detail view.

Which will be the best way to implement this?

I tried it with two UIApplicationDelegate Objects which will be added to the window by touching on of the buttons but could get it working and I'm not sure if it is even possible. Maybe I should rather add a NavigationController and add NavController A & B, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have one `UINavigationController` and you can initialize it with a root view controller that holds both buttons for your "subapps".

That's it.

Basically, when you click a "subapp" button you are adding the first view controller of your subapp to the UINavigationController stack and further on if you have more view controllers for that specific subapp. When you click the back button (removing view controllers from the stack) all the way back to your initial root view controller, you can then click your other subapp button and add those subapp's view controllers to the stack instead.

Bottom line: you can and you should manage everything with just one `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Thank's a lot that really cleared my confused mind, hopefully the old existing subapp doesn't make a spanner in the works